# segmentation fault from changing char value in argv

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm trying to convert a string to its alphanumeric value and I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error every time I try to display argv[1]...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{        
    int key[strlen(argv[1])];
    for (int i=0,n=strlen(argv[1]);i<n;i++)
    {
        // i'm going to assume all command line arguments are alphabetic
        if(argv[1][i]<='Z')
            {argv[1][i]-='A';}
        else
            {argv[1][i]-='a';}

        key[i]=argv[1][i];
    }
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
}
```

I've looked around and a lot of answers have said that it came from dividing/modulo-ing by 0 but I don't do that at all.
I've commented and uncommented stuff and I saw that without the else statement, it works fine.  If the program works for the if statement, why should it give an error for the else statement??

Comment: Your (undisclosed) environment may not like that you are changing `argv[..]`. You don't know where that pointer points to, and you probably only have read-access.

Comment: If `argv[1][i]` is either `'A'` or `'a'`, it becomes 0, which changes the result of subsequent `strlen` calls in the for-loop... This doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Hmm @user3114046 could be right. What are you using to run this?

Comment: @Jongware: C99/C11 requires the strings pointed to by the `argv` array to be modifiable.

Comment: ".. convert a string to its alphanumeric value ..", so I guess "AbcZ" should be printed as "12326"? If so, this code is still pretty far from that.

Comment: I am amazed that this compiles. Don't array dimensions have to be constant expressions?

Comment: @0xbe5077ed: C99 allows variable-lengthed arrays (C11 makes them optional afair, though)

Comment: i was using compileonline c99, and it works if I assign argv[1][i] -'a' straight to key[i]... Nos posted an answer earlier and that's how I got it working, but the answer has been deleted or something... @Jongware I guess I should treat argv as read-only?? but mafso says otherwise..  oh and i'll add the for loop to print out key's values and stuff, i just wanted to see why something else was off, but it works now... thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: With my default compilation options, GCC tells me that `key` is set but not used, and `argc` is unused.  Those aren't dreadfully material to the crash, though.

Comment: @user2985684 Please provide an example of your run like "a.out abcd".  IOWs How did you set `argv[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `printf`-statement.

Do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{        
    int key[strlen(argv[1])];
    for (int i=0,n=strlen(argv[1]);i<n;i++)
    {
        // i'm going to assume all command line arguments are alphabetic
        if(argv[1][i]<='Z')
            {argv[1][i]-='A';}
        else
            {argv[1][i]-='a';}

        key[i]=argv[1][i];

        printf("%d ",argv[1][i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that `argv[1]` is still a `char*`, so all the values are interpreted as characters, not integers. These are not printable since they are in the range 0 - 26. You want to output them one by one as integers.

This also might explain an input-dependent segmentation fault if the output string has no valid end anymore, but I cannot reproduce that.